# Right matrix division in Scipy/NumPy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a MATLAB expression:

```
x = B / A
```

when `B` and `A` are matrices.

This operator is equal to MATLAB function `mrdivide(B, A)`, that solves the equation system xA = B.

Don't we have the realization of the function in NumPy or SciPy?

Comment: `np.linalg.solve`?

Comment: Well, `np.linalg.solve` finds the solution of `Ax=B`, and I want `xA=B`.

Comment: @Felix: `x*A=B` is equivalent to `A.'*x.'=B.'`